# Remote Access on WAMP Server

Tags: port-forwarding, wamp

I am trying to connect my WAMP Server remotely over internet. I have a ADSL router (I also have a static IP provided by ISP) WAMP Server (Running on a local IP 192.168.1.150 and port 8080)

I can connect this server with the Ip Address -> 192.168.150:8080 from the another computer in the same network.

Please kindly help me to configure my server to access remotely through internet as IP Address -> mystaticIPbyISP

I am using a DSL Router Model DNA-A211-I And I made the NAT->Virtual Server forwarded to 192.168.150

```
Server Name External Port Start External Port End   Protocol    Internal Port Start Internal Port End   Server IP Address   Remove
Web Server (HTTP)        8080           8080             TCP        8080         8080            192.168.1.150
```

My prot 8080 also not block I have check it from http://canyouseeme.org/

Whenever I put my staticIPAddress given by my ISP in the browser it always open the Router Setting page.

I also tried by forwarding the external port 80 to internal port 8080 also.

Comment: You put your static IP address in the browser and it gives you the router settings page? That's a whole other insecurity in itself, but are you inputting your static IP followed by :8080? If your router is properly configured to forward port 8080 to 192.168.1.150, it should be loading that page that Apache is serving.

Comment: yes i try puting the :8080, i got a message as unable to access the network.